# Edit HTML that is in a <textarea> using GrapesJs

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

**I want to provide a visual editor to an HTML snippet that is currently edited using a simple `<textarea>` field.**

I am trying to learn GrapesJs to achieve this, but I can't grasp the idea. As far as I understood GrapesJs is rendered into the specified `<div>`, possibly taking the same `<div>` contents as it's initial template to edit, and then I guess it modifies the DOM or stores its work in browser storage.

If I understand it correctly I still can't get how to change this behaviour to deal with my `<textarea>` situation. I need the editor to take the `<textarea>` contents as its initial template and eventually put the modified HTML snippet back into it as text (?). So we don't need to store our DOM anywhere or send the HTML to server. The form in which this `<textarea>` is will be responsible to put it to the backend.

This also makes me wonder how GrapesJs can be separated from the form on which the `<textarea>` is placed, which may have its own styles and code.

And what will Grapes do to the styles and javascripts of the page being edited? Will they be the part of the text that GrapesJs will produce?...

**I will appreciate a small code example that will open up a GrapesJs visual editor that will take and store its work to/from a `<textarea>`**

*I can create two `<textarea>`s for html and styles if it is unavoidabe*

(I find the docs confusing for my level of knowledge in terms of logical separation of the editor itself and the page that we are editing, I currently fail to get my head around these notions in the docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated

I think in this case you can hook into `component` events like add, update, remove to update your textareas.

In the following example I'm doing so [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jvas28/pen/MWaXGyW)

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
            height: '100%',
            container: '#gjs',
            showOffsets: true,
            fromElement: true,
            noticeOnUnload: false,
            storageManager: false,
            plugins: ['grapesjs-preset-webpage'],
          });
    const htmlTextarea = document.getElementById('html')
    const cssTextarea = document.getElementById('css')
    const updateTextarea = (component, editor)=>{
      const e = component.em.get("Editor");
      htmlTextarea.value= e.getHtml();
      cssTextarea.value= e.getCss();
    }
    editor.on('component:add', updateTextarea);
    editor.on('component:update', updateTextarea);
    editor.on('component:remove', updateTextarea);
    const updateInstance = () => {
      editor.setComponents(htmlTextarea.value)
      editor.setStyle(cssTextarea.value)
    }
    document.getElementById('save').onclick=updateInstance;
```

Comment: Thank you! Am I correct to assume that this solution never takes its data from the textareas, only puts it there?

Comment: just can't find `setHtml`/`setCss` functions of the editor...

Comment: Thanks! The "Save" button allows the initial load, the subsequent button clicks break things up.. but it's okay! I think I've got the idea how to load data into the editor. By the way it works better if I swap `setStyle` and `setComponents`. Seems like setting components first affects the styles and then we set the styles again. But it's just a guess. Thanks again!

Comment: You are right, check last update, now you can do it in both ways :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Storage Manager of the [GrapesJS](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Storage.html)

```js
// Inline storage
const inlineStorage = (editor) => {
  const projectCssEl = document.getElementById("css");
  const projectHtmlEl = document.getElementById("html");
  console.log(projectHtmlEl);
  editor.Storage.add("inline", {
    load() {
      editor.setComponents(projectHtmlEl.value);
    },
    store(data) {
      const component = editor.Pages.getSelected().getMainComponent();

      projectCssEl.value = editor.getCss({ component });
      projectHtmlEl.value = `<html>
          ${editor.getHtml({ component })}
        <html>`;
    }
  });
};

// Init editor
grapesjs.init({
  container: "#gjs",
  height: "500px",
  plugins: [inlineStorage, "grapesjs-preset-webpage"],
  pluginsOpts: {
    "grapesjs-preset-webpage": {
      // options
    }
  },
  storageManager: { type: "inline" }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#css, #html {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grapesjs textarea</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css">
<script src="//unpkg.com/grapesjs"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/grapesjs-preset-webpage@1.0.2/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="html"></textarea>
    <textarea id="css"></textarea>
            <div id="gjs">
  <h1>Hello World Component!</h1>
</div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/andrejro2/pen/vYryXrg) with a working code